# Отправка фото с сервера (Ubuntu 20.04+Apache2+PHP) telegram ботом

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Телеграм бот написан на PHP, отправляет текстовые сообщения, разобрался как отправлять фото, но только если их брать по url.

Но как отправлять фото хранящиеся на самой машине, по соседству с основным файлом скрипта?

```
<?php
function sendMessage($chatID,$text,$buttons="",$reply=""){
        include $path.'var/vars.php';
        $markup = "";
        if($reply!=""){
            $markup.="&reply_to_message_id=".$reply;
        }
        
        if($buttons!=""){
            $markup.="&reply_markup=".$buttons;
        }
        file_get_contents($website.
                        "sendPhoto?chat_id=".$chatID.
                        "&text=".$text.
                        "&photo=https://example.com/img/hello.png".
                        "&parse_mode=HTML".$markup
                        );
}
?>
```

Comment: Параметр `photo` [может быть](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto) как URL-адресом, так и непосредственно фотографией в формате `multipart/form-data`

Comment: можно подробней, что это значит, что нужно дописать?

Answer (score 0):

Переделал следующим образом, как отправить через file_get_contents не нашел:

```
<?php
function sendMessage($chatID,$text,$image){
    include $path.'var/vars.php';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                         "Content-Type:multipart/form-data"
                                              ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $website."sendPhoto?");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
                          "chat_id" => $chatID,
                          "caption" => $text,
                          "photo" => new CURLFile(realpath("imagepath/".$image)),
                          "parse_mode" => "HTML"
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize("imagepath/".$image));
    $output =curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
?>
```